# How to tell if a jquery overlay has been cancelled

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

I am using a jQuery Tools overlay to present a dialog box to the user.  If the user clicks on the close button, I need to trigger an event noting that fact.  The code I wrote to do it works in Chrome and IE, but fails in Firefox on both Mac and Windows.

(the onClose property is part of the object I use to initialize the overlay)

```
  onClose: function(e) {
      if ($(e.srcElement).hasClass('close') || $(e.srcElement).hasClass('cancelButton')) {
            var trigger = this.getTrigger();
            var thisOverlay = this;
            $(document).trigger('overlayCancelled', [trigger, thisOverlay]);
  }
```

In Firefox, e.srcElement is undefined.  So is e.originalTarget.  Does anyone know of a workaround for this issue?

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 1):

In FF, e.originalEvent.originalTarget has a handle to the element used to close the overlay.  I used e.srcElement || e.originalEvent.originalTarget.

Thanks,
Rob